# Equals overloading in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to overload `compareTo` and `equals` operators for my class.

There is no problem with compare operator. It works well both as member and as an extension function.

The equals operator must be a member and override equals fun.

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        private val NUMBER: Int = 5

        operator fun compareTo(value: Int) = NUMBER - value

        override operator fun equals(other: Any?) =
                when (other) {
                    is Int -> NUMBER == other
                    else -> throw Exception("")
                }
    }
}

fun test() {
    if (MyClass < 10) {
        //ok
    }

    //Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'MyClass.companion' and kotlin.Int
    if (MyClass == 5) {
    }
}
```

**Edit:** How to overload '==' properly?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would want this. A correctly implemented `equals` method would always return `false` for a companion object except for when compared with itself (which is the default/inherited behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining `equals` and `hashCode` is considered somewhat useless on `object` declarations that have no explicit supertype, according to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9778). Probably correct `equals`+`hashCode` implementations on `object`s have few use cases.

There's even an IDE inspection that shows a warning when you try to do so:

[image: IDE warning screenshot]

<sup>The warning is not there when the object has a declared supertype.</sup>

However, I don't think that some technical reason stops Kotlin from resolving the overloaded operator, and the whole behaviour is strange, so I filed [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11827) in Kotlin issue tracker.

As for now (Kotlin 1.0.2 EAP), even with declared supertype you can only check `object`'s equality with instances of *exactly the same **declared** type* which it has as a supertype:

```
object SomeObject : List<Int> by listOf() { ... }
SomeObject == listOf(1, 2, 3) // OK
SomeObject == arrayListOf(1, 2, 3) // not resolved (why?)

object MyObject : Any() { ... }
MyObject == 1 // error
MyObject == 1 as Any // OK o_O

object AnotherObject { ... }
AnotherObject == 1 as Any // works! Probably Any is supertype here
```

As to defining `equals` as an extension function: no, you can't do it because **[extensions are resolved statically](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically)** and are shadowed by members (there's a similar [question about `toString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970957/how-to-extend-a-dataclass-with-tostring)).

Answer (score 1):

i think your implementation is the right approach

consider this:

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {
         private val NUMBER: Int = 5
         private val STRING: String = "foo"

         override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
                  when(other){
                     is MyClass -> {
                        return this.NUMBER == other.NUMBER &&
                               this.STRING == other.STRING
                      }
                     else -> return false
                 }
      }
}
```