# Problems defining equals() operator

Tags: operator-overloading, kotlin

I have a class

```
open class Texture
```

and I'd like to define the `equals(other: Texture)` operator

`operator fun equals(other: Texture) = ...`

but I get

> Error:(129, 5) Kotlin: 'operator' modifier is inapplicable on this function: must override ''equals()'' in Any

What does it mean?

If I change that to

`operator fun equals(other: Any) = ...`

> Accidental override, two declarations have the same jvm signature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`equals()` operator function is defined in `Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/#any), so it should be overriden with a compatible signature: its parameter `other` should be of type `Any?`, and its return value should be `Boolean` <s>or its subtype</s> *(it's final)*:

```
open class Texture {
    // ...

    override operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean { ... }
}
```

Without [the `override` modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-members), your function will clash with the `Any::equals`, hence the accidental override. Also, `equals()` cannot be an extension ([just like `toString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970957/how-to-extend-a-dataclass-with-tostring)), and it cannot be overriden in an interface.

In IntelliJ IDEA, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to override a member, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to generate `equals()`+`hashCode()`

Comment: Updated the answer due to the update of the question.

Comment: How do you arrange for the function to return `false` when `other` is not an instance of `Texture`?

Comment: @saulspatz: I guess the first line lines could be `if (other == null || other !is Texture) return false`